# PHP - Replace split

Tags: php

I have these 2 functions in which I have to replace split with another php command:

```php
function date_fr_mysql($date) {
    list($jour,$mois,$annee)=split("/",$date);
    $date = $annee."-".$mois."-".$jour;
    return $date;
} 
    
function date_mysql_fr($date) {
    list($annee,$mois,$jour)=split("-",$date);
    $date = $jour."/".$mois."/".$annee;  
    return $date;
}
```

with which function I can replace it to get the same result?

Comment: May I ask why you have to replace split?

Comment: Because Split has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Comment: It looks like you're trying to translate date formats from US to French.  If you're doing this a lot, you might want to look at the IntlDateFormatter class  http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

Comment: In the OP's code (and in most uses of split, at least in my experience) this works great. In some cases though the functions aren't identical, as `split` supports regular expressions whereas `explode` does not. For ones that use regular expressions, `preg_split` is the go-to replacement. When you don't need this functionality, `explode` is faster.

Answer (score 5):

The function `explode` is similar to `split`, except it does not regexes. Use `preg_split` if you need regex support.

Answer (score 2):

I have this example from PHP manual on split function over date:

```
<?php  
// Delimiters may be slash, dot, or hyphen                     `

    $date = "04/30/1973";  
    list($month, $day, $year) = split('[/.-]', $date);  
    echo "Month: $month; Day: $day; Year: $year";  
?>
```

After some experimentation, the solution to avoid a deprecated warning and still have the same result is:

```
<?php  
    // Delimiters may be slash, dot, or hyphen  
    // test preg_split per /
     $valore2 = "2010/01/01";

    //list($month, $day, $year) = split('[/.-]', $valore2);
    list($year, $month, $day) = preg_split('[/|\.|-]', $valore2);
    echo "Month: $month; Day: $day; Year: $year\n";

    // test preg_split per -
    $valore2 = "2010-01-01";

    //list($month, $day, $year) = split('[/.-]', $valore2);
    list($year, $month, $day) = preg_split('[/|\.|-]', $valore2);
    echo "Month: $month; Day: $day; Year: $year\n";

    // test preg_split per .   
    $valore2 = "2010.01.01";

    //list($month, $day, $year) = split('[/.-]', $valore2);
    list($year, $month, $day) = preg_split('[/|\.|-]', $valore2);
    echo "Month: $month; Day: $day; Year: $year\n";
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems like overkill! Check out the solutions using `explode`; the OP wasn't using the regular expressions capability of `split`, so that solution not only works, but it offers a performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

Given it seems you're just changing `-` to `/`, how about

```
$date = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
```

Comment: the order of year, month and day is also being reversed, so it's a bit more than just str_replace()

Comment: true 'nuff. Though since it's mysql_fr and fr_mysql, should be much easier to just format the dates in mysql to begin with, rather than doing processing in php.

Answer (score 1):

```
date ( 'Y-m-d', strtotime ( $your_date ) );
```

Comment: much better to treat a date as a date rather than as a string.